# Move scrollbar programmatically based on selection - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an autocomplete box that populates a list of options.

An image is as follows

[image]

The list options will be **scrolled down using down arrow**. When the down arrow is pressed, I need to programmatically move the scrollbar based on the selection.

The code is as follows.

HTML

```
<div id="search-location-result" class="autocomplete-active">
   <ul class="list-group" id="search-result-display-id">
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
     <li>Dallas, Texas United States. A long address</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(locationField).on('keydown', function(e) {


      var key = e.keyCode,
      $selected = $(listItems).filter('.selected'),
      $current;
      // Down key press
      if ( key == 40 ) {
        if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child') ) {
          $current = $(listItems).eq(0);
        }
        else {
          $current = $selected.next();
        }
        var currentScroll = $current.position().top;
        $(".list-group").scrollTop(currentScroll); 
      }

    });
```

The issue is that the scrollbar is not appearing correctly based on the selection.

That is, If we consider the attached image,

- the scrollbar needs to stay on top for the first four locations
- the scrollbar needs to move when the down arrow selects 'Dallas
  Kortukeli Antalya, Turkey'.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post full relevant code by either writting a fiddle or a snippet